# R-using the paste function in a loop is causing me problems

Tags: r

This is pretty simple, but I am wondering why the following doesnt work.

Works

```
myvars=c("JourneyTravelTime","PaxType") 
formula=as.formula(paste("SumAmountBooked~",paste(myvars,collapse="+")))
```

Output (text)

```
SumAmountBooked ~ JourneyTravelTime + PaxType
```

Doesnt work

```
i=1
formula=as.formula(paste("as.factor(Product",i,")",sep=""),paste(myvars,collapse="+"))
```

It then says object Product1 not found. I assume it is because I paste an object (i) with the other text that it looks for an object. is there a way to treat it as text anyways? I have tried wrapping as.character around different parts and it doesnt help.

Comment: I think you need to actually create the product object or use quotes (and the escape operator) around Product to indicate it is a string to be pasted: `\"Product\"`

Comment: What are you trying to do? You could do `form_as_string = paste(paste("as.factor(Product",i,")",sep=""),paste(myvars,collapse="+"), sep = " ~ ")` and wait to coerce it to a formula until your `Product1` variable is defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Careful inspection of your code will show that you are not actually passing a formula-like string to `as.formula` in the example that isn't working.  Let's step through and add some structure to your code.  We will put each argument to a function on its own line.

In your first example, which works, you are passing the strings `"SumAmountBooked~"` and `"JourneyTravelTime+PaxType"` into `paste`. The full string can be coerced to a valid formula.

```
myvars = c("JourneyTravelTime", 
           "PaxType") 
# Notice that you have only ONE argument to `as.formula`

formula = 
  as.formula(
    paste("SumAmountBooked~",
          paste(myvars,
                collapse="+"))
  )
```

In your next example, however, you are passing two strings to `as.formula`. This is causing R to look for the object `as.factor(Product1)` in the environment `"JourneyTravelTime+PaxType"`.  Since there is no environment of that name, the coercion to a formula fails.

```
i = 1
# Now you have TWO arguments to `as.formula`.  
# The second argument is the environment in which to find the first.
# You also have no '~'
formula=
  as.formula(
    paste("as.factor(Product",
          i,
          ")",
          sep=""),
    paste(myvars,
          collapse="+")
  )
```

One way to get the desired result would be as follows:

```
as.formula(
  paste0(
    paste0("as.factor(Product", 
           i, 
           ")"),
    " ~ ",
    paste(myvars, 
          collapse = "+")
  )
)
```

Personally, I'd be inclined to use `sprintf` to avoid putting in so many `paste` commands.  This can help keep the structure of your desired string together while you substitute in the pieces where the `%s`'s go.

```
as.formula(
  sprintf("as.factor(Product%s) ~ %s",
          i,
          paste0(myvars, collapse = "+"))
)
```